# given a date calculate date of week day in the same week

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-date-functions

I've got the following sql code I've hashed together to get the output I want from my timesheet data. Not sure its the most efficient way to retrieve data this way but seems to work. The only issue I have found is that the date displayed on some of the records are a week out. So if the timesheet date was 2015-12-02, when I am calculating the date for the monday of that week, I need to subtract '-7 days' as its bringing up the date for the following monday. I was thinking of doing this with variables, but reading up sqlite doesn't support variables. Anyone advise me the best way to approach this please.

I enclose the code I have below

```
SELECT 'Mon' , DATE(t.date, 'weekday 1') AS myDate , tl.projectID , t.staffID , tl.mon AS hours, t.date
FROM timesheet_line AS tl
LEFT JOIN timesheet AS t ON tl.timesheetID = t.timesheetID
LEFT JOIN staff AS s ON t.staffID = s.staffID
WHERE (t.date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2015-12-01') AND (tl.mon NOT Null) AND (tl.mon <> '')

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Tues' , DATE(t.date, 'weekday 2') AS myDate , tl.projectID , t.staffID , tl.tues AS hours, t.date
FROM timesheet_line AS tl
LEFT JOIN timesheet AS t ON tl.timesheetID = t.timesheetID
LEFT JOIN staff AS s ON t.staffID = s.staffID
WHERE (t.date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2015-12-01') AND (tl.tues NOT Null) AND (tl.tues <> '')

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Wed' , DATE(t.date, 'weekday 3') AS myDate , tl.projectID , t.staffID , tl.wed AS hours, t.date
FROM timesheet_line AS tl
LEFT JOIN timesheet AS t ON tl.timesheetID = t.timesheetID
LEFT JOIN staff AS s ON t.staffID = s.staffID
WHERE (t.date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2015-12-01') AND (tl.wed NOT Null) AND (tl.wed <> '')

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Thurs' , DATE(t.date, 'weekday 4') AS myDate , tl.projectID , t.staffID , tl.thurs AS hours, t.date
FROM timesheet_line AS tl
LEFT JOIN timesheet AS t ON tl.timesheetID = t.timesheetID
LEFT JOIN staff AS s ON t.staffID = s.staffID
WHERE (t.date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2015-12-01') AND (tl.thurs NOT Null) AND (tl.thurs <> '')

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Fri' , DATE(t.date, 'weekday 5') AS myDate , tl.projectID , t.staffID , tl.fri AS hours, t.date
FROM timesheet_line AS tl
LEFT JOIN timesheet AS t ON tl.timesheetID = t.timesheetID
LEFT JOIN staff AS s ON t.staffID = s.staffID
WHERE (t.date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2015-12-01') AND (tl.fri NOT Null) AND (tl.fri <> '')

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Sat' , DATE(t.date, 'weekday 6') AS myDate , tl.projectID , t.staffID , tl.sat AS hours, t.date
FROM timesheet_line AS tl
LEFT JOIN timesheet AS t ON tl.timesheetID = t.timesheetID
LEFT JOIN staff AS s ON t.staffID = s.staffID
WHERE (t.date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2015-12-01') AND (tl.sat NOT Null) AND (tl.sat <> '')

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Sun' , DATE(t.date, 'weekday 0') AS myDate , tl.projectID , t.staffID , tl.sun AS hours, t.date
FROM timesheet_line AS tl
LEFT JOIN timesheet AS t ON tl.timesheetID = t.timesheetID
LEFT JOIN staff AS s ON t.staffID = s.staffID
WHERE (t.date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2015-12-01') AND (tl.sun NOT Null) AND (tl.sun <> '')

ORDER BY myDate ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little backgound. The issue is that the `'weekday N'` modifier gives you the next date where day of the week == `N`. So if the date you provide the `Date` function is a monday and you ask `'weekday 0'`(sunday), it will give you the upcoming sunday, but if you ask`'weekday 2'`(tuesday), you will get tuesday for the current week because that date hasn't passed yet.

So, if you know that the date of the week on timesheet.date is always going to be a monday or whatever, you could just hardcode an adjustment to get back to the start of the week:
`Date(t.date, '-1 day', 'weekday 1')`

But if you don't want to make that assumption, you can use `strftime` to calculate your adjustment for each record :
`Date(t.date, strftime('-%w days',t.date), 'weekday 1')`